# how to handle JSON.stringify when string is empty

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to handle an object which doesn't exist in the array.

```
 var departureGate = JSON.stringify(data.flightStatuses[i].airportResources.departureGate);
```

So, when the javascript code gets here, it fall over because there happens to be nothing in the actual string it is trying to parse.  I've tried catching it with "typeof", but that doesn't work either.  I'm stumped.

So, the data.flightStatuses[i] array exists, just not the .airportResources.departureGate.

I tried to see if it exists using "typeof data.flightStatuses[i].airportResources.departureGate".  It still falls over.

```
alert (typeof data.flightStatuses[i])  // this comes back "object"
    alert (typeof data.flightStatuses[i].airportResources.departureGate)  // it dies...
```

Comment: Why don't you check if `data.flightStatuses[i].airportResources.departureGate` actually exists before trying to `JSON.stringify` it?

Comment: `if (data.flightStatuses[i]) ...`?

Comment: How exactly did you write your conditional for `typeof data.flightStatuses[i].airportResources.departureGate`?

Comment: Do you think you can set up a jsFiddle?

Comment: Wait - are you trying to PARSE JSON, or STRINGIFY JSON?

Comment: sorry....  Stringify  /  not parse

Answer (score 0):

Should be fairly straight forward like this:

```
if (data.flightStatuses[i].airportResources.departureGate) {
   var departureGate = JSON.stringify(data.flightStatuses[i].airportResources.departureGate);
}
```

Comment: Argh.  It dies.  It just doesn't like...   data.flightStatuses[i].airportResources.departureGate

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is with `airportResources`, and not with `departureGate`.

Try this:

```
var departureGate = null,
    ar = data.flightStatuses[i].airportResources;
if(ar && 'departureGate' in ar){
    departureGate = JSON.stringify(ar.departureGate);
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Yeah.  exactly....  if I look at the actual raw data... there are no airport resources...

Comment: Hey, awesome, Edgar!!   it got 'through' / didn't fall over.  working on it now.

Comment: Edgar....  i've never seen the "in" construct.  Does it mean what I think it means and it just goes out to see if the .departureGate "EXISTS"?

Comment: exactly, it means that

Comment: OK...  thanks, will continue to test and will add the solution when done.  Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the departuregate is defined as a property at all like this, and then do the action you wanted, for example:

```
if(data.flightStatuses[i].airportResources.hasOwnProperty('departureGate') {
    var departureGate = JSON.stringify(data.flightStatuses[i].airportResources.departureGate);
} else {
    var departuregate = null; // for example
}
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Comment: OK.  I tried Edgar's idea and it worked.  I'll continue to test that and if it works, great.  I'm thinking your idea will work too.  thanks much!